# How to prevent tomcat message output when saving servlet in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

How to prevent Tomcat from sending messages when saving Eclipse's servlet (.java)?

If you save Eclipse's servlet (.java), Tomcat continues to output a message to the screen, but closing it is too inconvenient.

How to prevent tomcat message output when saving servlet in eclipse?

Comment: What message are you referring to?

Comment: @Andreas https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/47sn

Comment: That's a wall of text. Maybe copy and paste just the relevant part *here*?

Comment: Which of all those messages are you referring to? If you mean all of them, then they are output because **Tomcat is reloading the web application**, so the code change can take effect, so what is it you want? 1) Not see Tomcat messages at all? Change the log level. 2) Not have changes take effect until you manually ask for it? Turn off auto-reloading.